# The TaskTracker spawns a new Mapper for each input split or for each key-value pair?

Tags: hadoop

I have found following question on some site , but I am not sure about correct answer .

> *Which Hadoop service in a MapReduce program spawns a new Mapper?*

1. The `JobTracker` spawns a new `Mapper` to process all the records in a single file.
2. The `TaskTracker` spawns a new `Mapper` to process each key-value pair.
3. The `TaskTracker` spawns a new `Mapper` to process all the records in a single input split.
4. The `JobTracker` calls the `TaskTracker`'s `configure ()` method, then its `map ()` method and finally its `close ()` method.

Site says Answer is option 2 , but I am confuse with Answer 3.

As in java doc of `mapper` I have found following thing :

> The Hadoop Map-Reduce framework spawns one map task for each `InputSplit` generated by the `InputFormat` for the job. `Mapper` implementations can access the Configuration for the job via `theJobContext.getConfiguration()`.
>   The framework first calls `setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context)`, followed by `map(Object, Object, Context)` for each key/value pair in the `InputSplit`. Finally `cleanup(Context)` is called.
>   All intermediate values associated with a given output key are subsequently grouped by the framework, and passed to a `Reducer` to determine the final output. Users can control the sorting and grouping by specifying two key `RawComparator` classes.

Comment: I actually found the same answers attached to a different question. The question is **Which process describes the lifecycle of a Mapper?** will the answer still be Option 3 in that case? Thank you!

Comment: @Ashrith Can you take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

It is 2

Map Task is JVM

Mapper is just a java class or an object

The job scheduler creates one Map Task for each split: (MapReduce1 page 191 Hadoop The Definitive Guide 3rd).

The Application Master creates a map task object for each split:(MapReduce2 page 199 of the same book).

Either case, it is not taskTrack spawns the Map task.

TaskTrack spawns Mapper class to handle each key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is option 3. Tasktrackers spawn the JVM in which mapper instance executes. A mapper always processes an entire inputsplit.

Answer (score 0):

As picked from Definitve  guide book, Option 3 is the correct answer. Below is what the book says

**The YarnChild runs in a dedicated JVM, for the same reason that tasktrackers spawn
new JVMs for tasks in MapReduce 1:**

Comment: Can you please take a look at my comment to the original question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be 2

Look the Mapper class code:

```
 public class MaxTemperatureMapper
     extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
```

It means the Mapper class/object will take one key/value pair each time, when this k/v pair is been processed, the class/object is done, it is finished. Next k/v pair will be processed by another Mapper, a new class/object.

Comment: I think this might not be correct because in this case overriding run method does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are two terms to be considered here.

- **Mapper** as in the Map task spawned by the Tasktracker in a separate
  JVM to process an input split. ( all of it ). For TextInputFormat , this would be a specific number of lines from your input file.
- **Map method** that is called for every record(key-value pair) in the split. Mapper.map(...) . In case of TextInputFormat, each map method (invocation)will process a line in your input split.

Answer 3 seems to be the most accurate answer in this context.

Reference :- The Definitive Guide Edition 3

Answer (score 0):

InputSplits as a whole are fed to the map tasks.

The splits in turn contain key-value pairs.

Files **->** Splits **->** Partitions in this order

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is option-3

2.The TaskTracker spawns a new Mapper  to process each key-value pair.

3.The TaskTracker spawns a new Mapper to process all the records in a single input split.

For me, it does not make sense to spawn a new Mapper for each key-value pair - Think of 64MB block size contains 1000 records(key-value pairs). I do not think framework creates 1000 mapper here.

A Mapper task process single input split( not a file or block or some of records)